# Examples of beings bestowed with the Vaishnava Sarshti Moksha?

Tags: vaishnavism, moksha

As per Srimad Bhagavatam there are 5 types of moksha

> 1.Salokya (living in same lok as god) eg:- Sant Tukaram of Maharashtra
>
> 2.Sameepya ( Always close to lord) eg:-Narad Muni
>
> 3.Saroopya (having similar form as lord) eg:- Gajendra Moksha
>
> 4.Sayujya (being one with lord)  Eg:- Shishupal, Kansa
>
> 5.Sarshti (enjoying opulence or divine powers)

My question is - I couldn't find any example of Sarshti moksha in scriptures. I searched a lot on internet also.

Can anyone give detailed examples of Sarshti moksha with scripture references. Please don't downvote this question as I have limited knowledge of scriptures

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: Well I think Sarshti Moksha means opulence enjoyment ('ऐश्वर्य भोग') and not powers of lord..

Comment: Well, i think it should be like becoming one of the highest ranking member (gana) of Vaikuntha and having both great opulence there and having same form as Lord Vishnu. As, in vaikuntha ganas like jaya, vijaya, vishvaksena etc has almost same form as Lord Vishnu.